# How to remove yellow highlighting of text in word file(.docx) using auto run Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

Word file with extension .docx is generated using apache poi. Due to restrict editing implemented generated document has yellow highlighting for the editable text .Is there any way to write macro to run automatically  and make shading off when word file is opened by user.

I tried AutoOpen() macro with ActiveDocument.View.ShadeEditableRanges = False , however its asking me to save file with macro enabled docm file which is not feasible for me , because I want to add macro in docx file.

Comment: It is impossible to add a macro to a docx.

Comment: If you add a macro to your [Normal template](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T013648_Protecting_Macros_in_the_Normal_Template.html), then you can run that macro against any loaded docx file.

Comment: «If you add a macro to your Normal template, then you can run that macro against any loaded docx file.» That won't help for anyone who doesn't have access to the OP's Normal template. Moreover, one might only want it to run against documents based on the template used to create the form... @Amruta: Why don't you just uncheck the 'Highlight the regions I can edit' option in the document's template? That way, there won't be any shading in the documents created by your apache code.

Comment: even If I uncheck it in the template and save it. After reopening the file again its checked and its word's default behavior that checkbox value is not stored